# obfuscate serialization class in java

Tags: serialization, proguard, obfuscation

I want to obfuscate our project to prevent the code from being cracked, So I used ProGuard to obfuscate. But our project contains many serialization classes or models（it's important and should be secret).And the ProGuard can not do this. So what can I do to protect these serialization classes or models from being decompiled?

Comment: Are you saying your program relies on your serialization classes/models beind unobfuscated?

Comment: yes, our program need these serialization classes/models to analyze data. Do you have any good idea?@Dank Vader

Comment: What you may want to look into is packing classes. It will keep the names the same but hide your classes as a jumbled up mess until they are decrypted at runtime.

Here's an open source example of a packer: https://github.com/redpois0n/jcrypt

On the note of "preventing the code from being cracked", this is impossible. It's just a matter of how much time and effort will be required to do so. If you really want to keep your code safe you will have to keep it server-side.

Comment: What you could do is, when it's time to deploy, obfuscate the classes yourself. Sounds like a pain, but would work. This could work by adding a new "obfuscation" package, copying all your serializable classes to it, then obfuscating then. Use that package for deployment, use your usual classes for development. Not automated, but still a work around. I'll probably do this unless class packing looks good. Not heard of that before. But, in general the APK is available for all to decompile, so with enough time anyone can get and understand your code. Put security critical code on your server !